# What's the term for cutting part way through a vegetable or fruit to increase surface area?

Tags: language, knife-skills

The other day I braised beef asian style (a bit of weak beef stock, sweet soy syrup, and dark soy sauce if you're wondering), and I put in some ginger. I wanted to keep the ginger together but give the most surface area to let its flavors out, so I cut into sticks which were still connected to the base. I was explaining to someone what I'd done, but I could not come up with a name for what I did.

What is the name for this technique?

Comment: This is generally known as fanning.

Comment: I've heard someone call it 'book cut' before, but using search engines for that term to determine if it's common was pretty useless.

Comment: @jbarker2160, a fan cut is generally for presentation, but closer than anything else I've found

Comment: I'd bet there's a name for it in Chinese.

Comment: Maybe I get to name it!

Answer (score 1):

I think the term you are looking for is accordion cut. It is the technique you describe, making slices not all the way through, leaving an end or side intact.

It is most widely known for preparation of hasselback potatoes, but can also be used for meat and other items. Please see pics below of hasselback potatoes and meat.

[image]

[image]

Other times that I have used this cut is when fine dicing celery and other veggies and, quite similar to your use, when using a block of salt meat for seasoning vegetables.

Comment: I don't think that's it @Cindy, an accordion cut is used only on meat, cutting alternating top and bottom cuts to make a thicker piece of meat stretch.